# Concave function. How do we prove splitting is not good?

Tags: proof-verification, summation, convex-analysis

I would like to prove the following statement, in generic form, for $f>0$ - concave function:

$$Af\left( \frac{x}{A}\right) > a_1f\left( \frac{x}{a_1}\right) + a_2f\left( \frac{x}{a_2}\right)+ \dots+ a_Nf\left( \frac{x}{a_N}\right), $$ 
where $x>0$ and:
$$\sum_{i=1}^N a_i = A.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, you are trying to prove that $f(x)\gt \frac{1}{2}f(2x)+\frac{1}{3}f(3x)+\frac{1}{6}f(6x)$, with $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{6}=1$.

I am not convinced this can be proven at all. Take $f(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}+C$ (with a big enough $C$), which is concave on $(1,+\infty)$, and let $x\to 1+0$. The LHS diverges (to $-\infty$) while the RHS converges (to $-\frac{3}{10}$) so the inequality must be broken for $x$ close enough to $1$.

Start with $C=0$ and then, once such $x$ is found so that the inequality is broken, increase $C$ to get to another counterexample, where the function is also positive on $[x, \infty)$.

Comment: Hi, I added a constraint for $f$ to be positive. For example: $$100 \log f\left(\frac{x}{100}\right)> 20 \log f\left(\frac{x}{20}\right)  + 50 \log f\left(\frac{x}{50}\right) + 30 \log f\left(\frac{x}{30}\right)$$

Comment: @Miroslav But that's not gonna help. Take my function from the answer above, find the $x$ that gives you a counterexample, now add a big enough constant $C$ (i.e. define $g(x)=f(x)+C$) and you will still have $g$ concave and $x$ is a counterexample for $g$. By choosing $C$ big enough you can also make $g$ positive at the relevant interval.

Comment: @Miroslav I think the fundamental flaw here is that the value $x/A$ is not necessarily in the convex hull of the points $x/a_1, \ldots, x/a_n$.